# CodeIgniter - AJAX Upload error: Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

When the file is uploaded, I get the following return error:

{"status":"error","msg":"Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again."}

Here is my server side code:

```
public function upload_file(){
        $status = "";
        $msg = "";
        $file_element_name = 'files';

        if ($status != "error")
        {
            $base_url = base_url();
            $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
            {
                $status = 'error';
                $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
            }
            else
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_id = $this->Rate_model->insert_file($data['file_name']);
                if($file_id)
                {
                    $status = "success";
                    $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
                }
                else
                {
                    unlink($data['full_path']);
                    $status = "error";
                    $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
                }
            }
            @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
        }
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Rate_model" is failing, we need to see the model. Also $status != "error" is void

Comment: I agree with @Philip, the status is void because it will always be blank. Provide your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use your model, you first need to load it, make these changes:

```
 $this->load->model('Rate_model');
 $file_id = $this->Rate_model->insert_file($data['file_name']);
```

if this does not work, then the problem lies in your model method. You will need to provide us with that code so that we can continue inspecting it.